# update_post_meta or woocommerce product object?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question, is there any deference between update product price with `update_post_meta()` or using woocommerce product object? i.e. get product object with given product id and use `$product->set_price($price)`

are both of theme valid?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference both are valid.